# Regular Expression in Bash Script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, expression

I'm trying to check if a string matches this format:

```
10_06_13
```

i.e. todays date, or a similar date with "2digits_2digits_2digits".

What I've done:

```
regex='([0-9][0-9][_][0-9][0-9][_][0-9][0-9])'
if [[ "$incoming_string" =~ $regex ]]
then
   # Do awesome stuff here
fi
```

This works to a certain extent. But when the incoming string equals `011_100_131`, it still passes the regex check. How can I fix my regex to only accept the right format?

Comment: Note that the underscores don't need to be in square brackets. `_` matches the same thing as `[_]`.

Comment: 011_100_131 would not match with your regex. 011_10_131 would.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`=~` succeeds if the string on the left *contains* a match for the regex on the right. If you want to know if the string *matches* the regex, you need to "anchor" the regex on both sides, like this:

```
regex='^[0-9][0-9][_][0-9][0-9][_][0-9][0-9]$'
if [[ $incoming_string =~ $regex ]]
then
  # Do awesome stuff here
fi
```

The `^` only succeeds at the beginning of the string, and the `$` only succeeds at the end.

Notes:

1. I removed the unnecessary `()` from the regex and `""` from the `[[ ... ]]`.
2. The bash manual is poorly worded, since it says that `=~` succeeds if the string matches.

Comment: Damn, I was so close! I presumed '^' was to exclude characters. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Robbie: `^` means "excluding" when it is the first thing in a character set (`[...]`), and it means "anchored" when it is the first thing in a pattern. Otherwise, it just matches `^` (but that's not true in all regex implementations; sometimes it means "match the beginning of a line"). I agree that it's confusing until you get used to it.

Comment: as mentioned above, you could replace `[_]` with `_` without changing what the regex matches.